# Integrate just gives me back what I put in

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a curve in a three dimensional space and I want to get the arc length function. So I defined the curve and its velocity and asked for the integral of the norm of its speed:

```
alpha[t_] := {Cosh[t], Sinh[t], t}
alphap[t_] := D[alpha[t], t]
Integrate[Norm[alphap[t]], t]
```

I got back

```
\[Integral]Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cosh[t]]^2 + Abs[Sinh[t]]^2] \[DifferentialD]t
```

I tried it with Rubi:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\genen\\Rubi4.15\\Rubi.m"]
Int[Norm[alphap[t]], t]
```

and got back:

```
 Int[Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cosh[t]]^2 + Abs[Sinh[t]]^2], t]
```

How can I get the system to give me the integral, or is it just that a closed form does not exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, MMA assumes expressions to be complex:

```
Norm[{x,y,z}]
```

> Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[y]^2 + Abs[z]^2]

---

If you look at `Norm[alphap[t]]`, there's an `Abs` raised to the second power - hence, for real values, the `Abs` is redundant. Simply getting rid of it still requires an assumption that $t\in \mathbb{R}$, so let's go directly there:

```
Integrate[Norm[alphap[t]], t, Assumptions -> t ∈ Reals]
```

> Sqrt[2] Sinh[t]

---

Also one could `Simplify` the integrand with the assumption:

```
Integrate[Simplify[Norm[alphap[t]], t ∈ Reals], t]
```

> Sqrt[2] Sinh[t]

but it's to convoluted compared to `Assumptions`, and redundant.

Comment: How to I get the "member of" symbol you used? (the backwards E)

Comment: [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html)

Comment: Also: <Esc> elem<Esc>